# Is it possible to not render a hidden field in client side in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In asp.net a hidden field can not be rendered in client side by having `visible="false"`.
Is it also possible in mvc 3 to not render a hidden field in client side?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a condition:

```
@if (IsVisible)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Foo)
}
```

or write a custom HTML helper which will allow you to pass the condition to the helper directly:

```
@Html.MyHiddenFor(x => x.Foo, IsVisible)
```

which could be implemented like this:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyHiddenFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        bool isVisible
    )
    {
        if (!isVisible)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        return htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you darin. so this can be travel through a form POST without losing the value and it is equivalent to asp.net:Hidden Field control with visible ="False"?

Comment: @jeff, I don't understand what you mean by *travel through a form POST*. Contrary to ASP.NET, in ASP.NET MVC there's no viewstate. So you need to have each controller action pass a corresponding view model to the view containing all the necessary data that this view requires.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I understand that view state is no longer implemented in asp.net. However, My question is: Using your solution, the hidden field will not rendered to client side but can extract its value in server side because asp.net can extract the data in a hidden field without rendering it in client side.

Comment: No, you cannot extract its value as it is no longer present in the form so nothing gets submitted to the server. If you want to fetch the value on the server you should leave the hidden field in the markup.